# JQuery start file download then run a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect

I have the following jQuery code that redirects to download a file after certain amount of seconds. In that time, I am showing a please wait icon. Once the file download has started by redirecting to the new URL, I want to be able to also then run a function called unloadFrame(). Problem is that because the the page is changing, I cannot run the unloadFrame function.

Any ideas how I can achieve this?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        location.href = "export.xls";
        unloadFrame();    
    }, 5000)
});
```

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

OK i've done the following which seems to work. does anyone have any other ideas or better options:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    location.href = "export.xls";

    window.setTimeout(function () {
     unloadFrame();
    }, 8000)
});
```

Comment: have you actually tried to run unloadFrame after the location.href? an alternative is to do the file download through a hidden iframe.

Comment: You could always use a (hidden) iframe to download the file, and keep doing stuff in the main window at the same time.

Comment: I did try the unloadFrame after the redirect. I've updated the code to show how i tried it. It does seem to run the unloadFrame function but since my file download has a slight delay and doesnt start straight away it ends up ignoring it.

Comment: have you tried attaching to the window.onunload event? $(window).on( "unload", unloadFrame ); before location.href = 'export.xls'.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onunload

Answer (score 0):

You cannot download a file like that with JavaScript. Maybe create an `iframe`, set it's URL to something that returns a download page (with the appropriate HTTP headers), then do your `unloadFrame`.

Comment: You can download a file like that, you just can't navigate the page away and expect to still be able to do stuff with it

Comment: Yes, thanks for clarifying that, as the download page will replace the current one.